# Create excel spreadsheet file in ios

Tags: ios, excel, csv, textfield

I am creating an application where the user will have to type in specific information into text fields and export it in email, then send it to themselves in CSV or .xls format. I would say my level of experience with xcode and ios development is intermediate so if you could provide some sample code or point me in the right direction I'm sure I could figure it out.

Comment: This is actually a far more generic question than just iOS.   With the exception of Windows (where components of office expose COM interfaces and are scriptable),  the solution is likely the same on any other platform.  Creating xls files is likely hard work.  xlxs files are a much better bet.

Comment: Ok, could you possibly provide me with a website where i can find more information on .xlxs spreadsheets and how to integrate them with ios.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try this http://xcodetipss.blogspot.in/2013/11/create-excelxls-file-programatically-in.html?

I think its useful for you.